# Where to upload my files to on openshift?

Tags: server, ftp, uploading

I have a node app that I want to upload on openshift.

I have already managed to create a public/private key and am able to sftp to my server. However, when I enter what I see is the following:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/694cba5ef7e242a33ce3f6e013bac9fd.png]

I have no idea where I should drop my files. In other words, if I had a hello world index.html file, to which folder would I upload it to so as to see 'HELLO WORLD' when i went to example.com?

Answer (score 3):

Very similar question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22719121/2268476)

> If you're looking to find the webroot of your application running its
>   `app-root/runtime/repo`. However, I would strongly suggest you make
>   changes through Git if you're altering code. If your uploading things
>   like pictures or other data, you'll want to store them in your
>   $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR which is located at /app-root/data/